# Robust covariance estimate?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

I have come across this calculation in a script involved in some principal component analysis:

```
ddata = data'*data;

ddata = max(ddata,ddata');
```

The resulting matrix `ddata` is used where I would normally expect a covariance matrix. `data` is a matrix containing data vectors as its rows.

This is not how I would normally calculate a covariance estimate, so I was wondering - is this some kind of robust covariance estimate?
I have tried to look it up, but I only found a so-called sandwich estimate, which does not seem to be this.